# How can I set the new directory structure when updating Symfony2.8 to Symfony3.0?

Tags: php, composer-php, symfony, directory-structure

So I have this website I initially developped with Symfony `2.8.6`. I updated `composer.json` file to Symfony `3.0` and ran `$ composer update`. It succesfully installed all new required vendors.

However, I'm still provided with the old directory structure:

- `cache/` directory is still in `app/` instead of `var/`
- `logs/` directory is still in `app/` instead of `var/`
- `console` file is still in `app/` instead of `bin/`

How come? What should I do?

---

[As requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37687398/how-can-i-set-the-new-directory-structure-when-updating-symfony2-8-to-symfony3-0/37687700#comment62863050_37687700), here's my `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "": "src/" },
        "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": { "Tests\\": "tests/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.7",
        "knplabs/knp-time-bundle": "^1.6",
        "eko/feedbundle": "^1.2",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master",
        "lexik/maintenance-bundle": "dev-master",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "5.3.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin",
        "platform": {
            "php": "5.6.16"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "3.1-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should check the `composer.json` files the extra section, as example:

```
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    }
```

More info in [this article](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony3-upgrade/new-dir-structure) 
Hope this help

Comment: Updating `composer.json` file only won't help as I have this exact snippet of JSON in mine. I will look further in the link provided but I won't accept the answer as is. Upvoted though.

Comment: Hi @D4V1D can you post your `composer.json` files?

Comment: Hi there! Just did!

Comment: You have to have `symfony-var-dir` set and the directory needs to be a directory. https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioDistributionBundle/blob/master/Composer/ScriptHandler.php#L464